# EOT and LOT vs EET and LET

Tags: ms-project, project-management-style, tasks, task-management

Are the Earliest Occurrence time and Latest occurrence time same as the Earliest Event time and Latest event time or are they different? If they are different can you please explain to me what are EOT and LOT.

Answer (score 1):

Earliest Occurrence Time (EOT) and Latest Occurrence Time (LOT) are terms used to figure out critical path when using critical path analysis.  The EOT is used for calculating the forward pass and LOT would be used to calculate the backward pass.  In Microsoft Project specifically, the scheduling engine uses Early Start / Early Finish and Late Start / Late Finish to run the critical path analysis on your schedule activities.

My understanding of Earliest Event Time and Latest Event Time is that they are used in a schedule that is built around events instead of activities.  These events are used the same way as activities to determine critical path in MS Project.

Usually a Work Breakdown Structure (WBS) is used to define activities which usually define products and an Integrated Master Plan (IMP) is a structure used to define events.

MS Project is built around Work Breakdown Structures, but if you need an IMP structure, you will have to define two or three custom fields to be able to properly track your IMP.